# how to solve boot menu problems in sony vaio laptop

Tags: 14.04

i have installed winndow 8.1 and ubuntu 14.04 in sonz vaio SVF15218SNB.after install no boot option see in screen and alwazs option window show.direct start window.i have install grab file but cannot see option.please tell me.

Comment: Turn off the computer and turn it on using ASSIST button.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to "fix" the grub - usually after major Windows updates - I use (http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) and do the recommended repair option. I use this to make bootable usb's - (http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) - however you want will be good bud.

Answer (score 0):

You could boot from a live Ubuntu usb, and type this in the terminal:

```
 sudo apt a add a repository ppa:yaunnu/boot-repair
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install boot-repair
 boot-repair
```

and use custom repair, and it might work fine this way.